# The fundamental group of the complement of an analytic subset of codimension at least $2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $V$ an analytic subset of $X$ of codimension $\ge 2$. By intuition, il might be true that the fundamental group of $X$ equals that of $X \backslash V.$ I would like to ask if the last claim is true or not and in the affirmative case, how do we prove it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is *yes*.

Just triangulate $X$ in such a way that $V$ is a subpolyhedron (this can be done by Lojasiewicz's theorem). Now it is well-known that removing a subpolyhedron of (real) codimension at least $3$ does not affect the fundamental group for transversality reasons.

**Edit.** Actually, Lojasiewicz's theorem is not necessary. In fact, the analytic subset $V$ provides a closed real submanifold of codimension at least $4$ of the underlying real manifold of $X$, so we can use the following result, whose proof can be found for instance in

C. Godbillon, *Eléments de Topologie Algebrique*, Théorème 2.3 page 146:

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a smooth, connected real manifold without boundary, $V \subset X$ a closed submanifold, $x$ a point of $X\setminus V$ and $i \colon X \setminus V \longrightarrow  X$ the inclusion map. Then
>
> - if the codimension of $V$ is at least $2$, the group homomorphism $$i_* \colon \, \pi_1(X \setminus V, \, x) \longrightarrow \pi_1(X, \, x)$$ is surjective;
> - if the codimension of $V$ is at least $3$, the group homomorphism $$i_* \colon \, \pi_1(X \setminus V, \, x) \longrightarrow \pi_1(X, \, x)$$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: thank you very much. Could you  give me a reference for the fact that removing a subpolyhedron of codim at least 3 does not affect the fundamental group? I am not familliar much with algebraic topology.

Comment: Real codimension at least three implies that you can "push away" any loop from $V$, and any homotopies beetween loops as well. From this you obtain the result. I will look for a proper reference, anyway.

Comment: Reference added.

Comment: Can one also prove this (for étale fundamental groups) using Grothendieck's criterion for surjectivity for étale fundamental groups, namely that the preimage of connected coverings remain connected? (And a similar criterion for injectivity.)

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Can you tell anything about the kernel of $i_*$ in the case of codimension exact $2$. I tried to follow the proof in the book but I can't figure out

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi An analytic subset need not be a real submanifold because of its singularities. Can we overcome this obstacle?

Comment: @francescoPolizzi Does the part of your answer before the edit assume smoothness of $V$?